# conditional validate react form fields using react-form-with-constraints

Tags: reactjs

I have two input fields that I want to conditional validate, for example, if field input one is not provided then make field input two required.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to not be supported out of the box by `react-form-with-constraints`. However you can use the `onChange` function to utilize a state that handles the validation for the second input field.

```
const [secondStepValidation, setSecondStepValidation] = useState(false);
const handleChange = v => {
   if (v.length === 0) {
       setSecondStepValidation(false);
   } else if (!secondStepValidation) {
       setSecondStepValidation(true);
   }
};


return (
 <>
    <input type="text" name="firstInput"
       value={this.state.password} onChange={handleChange}
       required pattern=".{5,}" />
    <input type="test" name="secondInput"
       value={this.state.user}
       required pattern=".{5,}" />
    {secondStepValidation && (
      <FieldFeedbacks for="password">
        <FieldFeedback when="valueMissing" />
        <FieldFeedback when="patternMismatch">
           Should be at least 5 characters long
     </FieldFeedback>
     <FieldFeedback when={value => !/\d/.test(value)} warning>
         Should contain numbers
     </FieldFeedback>
     <FieldFeedback when={value => !/[a-z]/.test(value)} warning>
        Should contain small letters
     </FieldFeedback>
     <FieldFeedback when={value => !/[A-Z]/.test(value)} warning>
        Should contain capital letters
     </FieldFeedback>
     </FieldFeedbacks>
   )}
 </>

)
```

Comment: Thanks, lemme try this one, will let you know.

Comment: Sorry for a late reply, somehow  something is not working right. Looks like it's still require both fields to be entered instead of checking whether field one was provided then make the other optional. I might be doing something wrong.

Comment: Could you mock the base functionality in a codesandbox?

Comment: Yes, @sebastian-ruehmann please have a look at this:  https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-bassi-5fo5f?file=/src/form.js

Comment: I have a custom inputComponent that I am using trying to achieve this.

Comment: Hey @Paul I forked your codesandbox and came up with a working approach. Basically I split your onChange function for the fields. Take a look: https://codesandbox.io/s/conditional-form-validation-cbe2o